# Cannot resolve method 'Snapshot(String)'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my android application i want to take the user details and verify them in my firebase database. but im having *Cannot resolve method 'Snapshot(String)'* problem.
There is my code

```
package com.example.ise435finalv2;

import static Model.User.getPassword;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import Model.User;

public class giris extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText kullaniciadiinput,sifreinput;
    Button Girisyap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_giris);

        sifreinput = findViewById(R.id.sifreinput);
        kullaniciadiinput = findViewById(R.id.kullaniciadiinput);
        Girisyap = findViewById(R.id.Girisyap);

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference table_user = database.getReference("User");

        Girisyap.setOnClickListener((View view) -> {

            final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(giris.this);
            mDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
            mDialog.show();

            table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange (@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                if(Snapshot(kullaniciadiinput.getText().toString()).exists()){
                   mDialog.dismiss();
                    User user = Snapshot(kullaniciadiinput.getText().toString()).getValue(User.class);
                    if (getPassword().equals(sifreinput.getText().toString()))
                        Toast.makeText(giris.this, "Giris basarili", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(giris.this, "Sifre yanlis", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
                else
                      Toast.makeText(giris.this, "Kullanici bulunamadi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


                @Override
                public void onCancelled (@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        });


    }
}
```

And there is my json file that uploaded to firebase database.

```
{
  "User": {
    "kenankaykci": {
      "Name": "Kenan",
      "password": "admin123"
    },
    "admin": {
      "Name": "admin",
      "password": "admin"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried `if(Snapshot(kullaniciadiinput.getText().toString()).exists()){`
Change but before this i was using `Datasnapshot.child(kullaniciadiinput.getText().toString()).getValue(User.class);`

When i had complier error i changed it to Snapshot. but it did'nt help. I also tried from android studio's helping tool but it didnt help.
Lastly im having 'user' variable is never used error but i have user.java file to send those parameters.
I have tried to change it noncapital user (User->user) but it didnt worked also.

Comment: There is an `exists()` method on `snapshot` object, but you apparently are trying to call a static or instance method called `Snapshot` on the `giri` class ... and you apparently didn't declare it.  It is hard to know how to fix this, because (frankly) I cannot figure out what you are actually trying to do in that call.

Comment: Its for if there is a username input verification. if it has a value it turns true but if its not than it returns to else.

Comment: But what is `Snapshot(kullaniciadiinput.getText().toString()).exists()` actually supposed to mean?  What is `Snapshot` supposed to be?  A method?  A class?  Where is it declared?  What does it return? How does this make sense?